# Methods in AbstractListModel to refresh JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

The JComboBox retrieves information from the database. The list should update immediately after data is added.

I am aware that I need to `fireContentsChanged` to the values to update. I am not sure what I should do in methods. Any guidance will be appreciated!

```
class ComboModel extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel 
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public Object getElementAt(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return list.size();     
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {


    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object arg0) {


    }           
}


stockListComboBox = new JComboBox();
ComboModel model = new ComboModel();
stockListComboBox.setModel(model);          

try
{
    // Database stuffs
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply some collection as the nucleus of your model, say an ArrayList or some other type of ordered list. Do this and the methods will start to make sense.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels, thanks for explaining. Do I need to use all the methods? I've been looking at several examples I am still lost. I'm not sure what should I be adding into the methods.

Comment: You need to override the abstract methods, the ones that are required. Give it a try and you'll likely figure it out, or at least come close.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you need to supply data.  The simplest way for a combo box is to use DefaultComboBoxModel which takes either an Object[] in it's constructor.   In general, the first two methods you have above are meant to 1) get elements in the list, 2) give back the size of the list.

The next two are meant for tracking which item in the list is selected.  I suggest looking at the javadocs.  Also, if you're using eclipse, netbeans or intellij, you should be very easily able to view the source code of DefaultComboBoxModel, and it should be apparantly obvious what those methods are doing.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the explanation. Do I need to use all the methods? I just need to retrieve the data from my database.